# Command line parameters for javaws

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start

I'd like to know how to send run time parameters to a JavaFX app stared via a JNLP file.

JNLP file snippet:

```
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.blah.Main"  name="Main" >
  <argument>blah1</argument>
  <argument>blah2</argument>
</javafx-desc>
```

This code snippet will retrieve the args:

```
List<String> list = this.getParameters().getRaw();
  for (String s : list) {
     System.err.println("args : " + s);
}
```

If the app is started as:

```
javaws http://localhost:8080/test/Main.jnlp
javaws Main.jnlp
```

the parameters are found and printed, so this is good. I really want to be able to modify the params when the app is launched.

According the javaws spec http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html
I should be able to do:

```
javaws -open newblah http://localhost:8080/test/Main.jnlp
javaws -open newblah Main.jnlp
```

This doesn't work. The arguements displayed are still those from the JNLP file.

I have also tried the "-J" option to supply options to the VM:

```
javaws -J-Dblah=something http://localhost:8080/test/Main.jnlp
javaws -J-Dblah=something Main.jnlp
```

and retrieving the parameters with this code:

```
System.getProperty("blah", "noblah");
```

This works for "javaws -J-Dblah=something Main.jnlp" but not when run via a URL. I'm guessing this is secrutiy issue. My JNLP has

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

and I have signed the app with a self signed key created with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore selfsigned.jks -storepass XXXXXXX -validity 3600 -keysize 2048
```

Finally, I have tried sending query parameters, such as:

```
javaws http://localhost:8080/test/Main.jnlp?blah=something
```

and retrieving them with this code:

```
public static Map<String, String> parseQueryParameters() {

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    String url = app.getHostServices().getDocumentBase().toString();
    System.err.println("url = " + url);

    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        String parameters = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
        StringTokenizer paramGroup = new StringTokenizer(parameters, "&");

        while (paramGroup.hasMoreTokens()) {
            try {
                StringTokenizer value = new StringTokenizer(paramGroup.nextToken(), "=");
                params.put(value.nextToken(), URLDecoder.decode(value.nextToken(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                System.err.println("error");
            }

        }
    }

    return params;
}
```

but the print line for the url string only returns:

```
url=http://localhost:8080/test/
```

I'd really like to know why I can't get something that should be straight forward to work.